# How to change username to connect to server in pgadmin4 in query tool?

Tags: users, pgadmin

Back in pgadmin 3, I could change the username in the query tool by clicking on `postgres on postgres@localhost:5432` dropdown:

[image: PGadmin 3 change user dialog box]

However, I don't see this option in pgadmin4. How do I change the user from postgres to some other user? Also, is there a way to set a user other than `postgres` as the default user in PGadmin 4?

Answer (score 1):

In PGAdmin4 the connection parameters are set at the Server level, not the Database level. So you need to right click on the server select disconnect and then right click on the server again and select Properties. In the Properties dialog change to the Connection tab and then change the Username that you will connect to the server with. You may need to change the maintenance database to something the user has access to. After doing this, when you open the Query Tool it will connect with your desired user.